# In Cinnamon desktop, running windows are not showing up in the taskbar

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop-environment

Linux mint 19.2 running cinnamon.   Attempting to resolve an issue where `cinnamon --replace` was pegging my CPU, I moved some items out of `/etc/xdg/autostart` and `~/.config/autostart`.

My taskbar now shows no buttons/icons for running windows.  The task bar is there, the quicklaunch buttons are there, the start menu is there.   Where the window icons/buttons should be is just a big grey strip.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

The things I removed from `/etc/xdg/autostart` were:

```
blueberry-obex-agent.desktop
blueberry-tray.desktop
caribou-autostart.desktop
cinnamon-settings-daemon-wacom.desktop
nm-applet.desktop
pulseaudio.desktop
```

I've put those back and restarted X to no avail.   I must have done something else, too.

What is the process or module that renders these buttons in the taskbar?

Comment: You might need to re-add the *Window List* applet to the panel.

Comment: @ajgringo619 - that did the trick!   Oddly the task buttons are right-justified on the taskbar now, but I can live with that.  Thanks!

Comment: Right-click the panel, select *Panel edit mode*. Now you can move any of the panel applets.